# Java Using Scanner Multiple Times

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I am having this problem a lot. When I use a Scanner a lot of times, it doesn't get input from user.

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("1---");

        int try1 = scan.nextInt();

        System.out.println("2---");

        int try2 = scan.nextInt();

        System.out.println("3---");

        String try3 = scan.nextLine();

        System.out.println("4---");

        String try4 = scan.nextLine();
```

When I run this code, result it :

1---

12

2---

321

3---

4---

aa

As you can see, it skipped at 3rd input. Why this is happening? I solve this problem by using new Scanners, sometimes I have 5-6 different Scanners and it looks so complicated.
Another problem is : there is an error "Resource leak: scan is never closed". I am really confused.

Comment: You typed 3, then 2, then 1, then <enter>. The `int` is 321. The <enter> is still waiting to be processed. Then the first `nextLine` call reads until the next <enter>, but there's already an <enter> you typed before, so it returns that line (which contained nothing). Consider what happens if you type "123 456 abc<enter>def<enter>"

Comment: Dude, the warning "Resource leak: scan is never closed". You need to close your scan. scanner.close();

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use next API rather than nextLine as when you do nextInt you press enter and it generates number + \n and nextInt is only going to take an integer and won't take \n which in turn gets passed to next input i.e. try3 which is why it gets skipped.

```
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("1---");

    int try1 = scan.nextInt();

    System.out.println("2---");

    int try2 = scan.nextInt();

    System.out.println("3---");

    String try3 = scan.next();

    System.out.println("4---");

    String try4 = scan.next();
```

Answer (score 9):

The problem is that by using `scanner.nextInt()` you only read an integer value, but not the whole line and you don't consume the newline character (`\n`) that is appended to the line when you press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Then, when you process reading with `scanner.nextLine()` you consume the newline character (`\n`) and from the previous row and don't read the line you want to read. In order to force it to read it, you have to add an additional `input.nextLine()` statement.

```
 System.out.println("2---");
 int try2 = scan.nextInt();
 System.out.println("3---");
 scan.nextLine(); //<-- fake statement, to move the cursor on the next line
 String try3 = scan.nextLine();
```

*Not related to the question*, you have to close the `Scanner`, after finishing work, otherwise the compiler complains with a warning:

```
scan.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, for the first question use

> scan.next()

insted of using

> scan.nextLine();

For the second question I'd recommend using try, assuming you need to close your scan as your compiler is warning: **"Resource leak: scan is never closed"**

```
Scanner scanner= null;
  try {
    scanner= new Scanner(System.in);

  }
  finally {
    if(scanner!=null)
    scanner.close();
 }
```