# program control not coming out of else if condition in Java

Tags: java, loops, if-statement, java.util.scanner, bluej

```
int pi_digits1=0;
int pi_digits2=0;

System.out.println("Would you like from starting to fixed no. or for a 
range:\n1.Fixed no\n2.Range");
byte choice = input.nextByte();

if(choice ==1){
    System.out.println("Enter the no. of digits after decimal within 1 million 
    of pi to see and play");
    pi_digits2=input.nextInt();
}
else if(choice ==2){
     System.out.println("Enter the smaller +ve no of range");
     pi_digits1=input.nextInt();
     System.out.println("Enter the larger +ve no of range");
     pi_digits2=input.nextInt();
     System.out.println("Check");
}
else{
    System.out.println("Wrong choice.Program terminated");
}
```

When the choice is 1,loop works fine.
But for the choice 2,after taking inputs for pi_digits2 ,it is still asking
for inputs.

Check is also being printed,but program is strucked in input loop and hence 
further code is not being executed.

[Program executed in Bluej environment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jwnyZ.png)

Comment: You are using `nextByte` when it seems like you want to use `nextInt`. The number `1` as a byte is `0x31`

Comment: Also, [look into this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26779492/1790644). Seems to be the same issue you face.

Comment: [I don't see an error?](https://ideone.com/OyTOlf)

Comment: Changing nextByte to nextInt doesn't help either

Comment: Shouldn't there be some sort of a loop if you want the code to repeat itself?